# Added Boostrap Checkbox in Symfony Form Collection missing bootstrap init

Tags: symfony, bootstrap-4, twig, symfony-forms

I'm currently trying to extend my symfony-form with the possibility to add custom collection entrys.
I followed the Manual https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html as close as possible (besides the structure of the form itself)

(Edit: I'm using Smyfony 3.4 and bootstrap 4 form style)

The problem is, that the checkboxes if the item, thats beeing added to the Collection-List seems to be missing the bootstrap-initialization. Therefore its not usable at all.

Is there a way to manually initialize the checkbox?

Here is the (simplified) code:

Formtypes:

```
class MissionReportFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('playerparticipations', CollectionType::class, [
                'allow_add'  => true,
                'entry_type' => PlayerParticipationsFormType::class, ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => MissionReport::class,
        ]);
    }
}

class PlayerParticipationsFormType extends AbstractSfoType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('delay', CheckboxType::class, ['required' => false]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => PlayerMissionParticipation::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
$missionReport = new MissionReport();
$missionReport->addPlayerparticipation(new PlayerMissionParticipation());

return $this->render ( 'SfoLcarsBundle::punktedokument.html.twig', array (
    'form' => $this->createForm(MissionReportFormType::class,$missionReport)->createView()
) );
```

Form

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive" id="punktedokument">
        <tbody id="punktedokument_entrys" data-prototype="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;{{ form_widget(form.playerparticipations.vars.prototype.delay)|e('html_attr')}}&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;">
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-pull-0 col-md-1"></th>
    </tr>
    {{ form_label(form.playerparticipations, 'Punktetabelle') }}
    {% for participation in form.playerparticipations %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_widget(participation.delay) }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Javascript

```
    var $collectionHolder;

    var $addParticipationButton = $('<button type="button" class="add_participation_link btn btn-primary">Neuer Eintrag</button>');
    var $newLinkLi = $addParticipationButton;

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $collectionHolder = $('tbody#punktedokument_entrys');
        $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);
        $collectionHolder.data('index',$collectionHolder.find('tr').length-1);
        $addParticipationButton.on('click', function(e) {
            addParticipationForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
        });
    });

    function addParticipationForm($collectionHolder, $newEntry) {
        var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');
        var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

        var newForm = prototype;
        newForm = newForm.replace(/__name__/g, index);
        $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);
        $newEntry.before(newForm);

    }
```

HTML of the initialy available TD:

```
<td>
    <div class="form-check">        
       <div class="icheckbox_minimal" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;">
<input type="checkbox" id="mission_report_form_playerparticipations_0_missing" name="mission_report_form[playerparticipations][0][missing]" class="form-check-input" value="1" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins></div>
       <label class="form-check-label" for="mission_report_form_playerparticipations_0_missing">Missing</label>
    </div>
</td>
```

Resulting HTML of the added TD:

```
<td>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="mission_report_form_playerparticipations_1_missing" name="mission_report_form[playerparticipations][1][missing]" class="form-check-input" value="1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="mission_report_form_playerparticipations_1_missing">Missing</label>
    </div>
</td>
```

[Result on the page - missing the Checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGfAG.png)

Comment: What do you by _manually initialize_? The Checkbox comes form the `data-prototype` and is set via JS which i would say is manual initialisation... If the resulting HTML when pressing the add button really is what you specified, then checkbox should work, if it does not, i would suggest, that there is a HTML/CSS problem...

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. 
I specified the prototype by using the prototype-values of symfony. I dont know what i could change there besides really putting all the bootstrap divs and labels around by hand. But that doesnt seem right. 

How can i get the "icheckbox_minimal" div around the checkbox. I know that that is done by some js-magic but that seems to be missing with the "onClick" generated checkbox.

Comment: @andyMay you should be fine with just calling the js init for the javascript plugin in your addParticiptionForm function.

Comment: @Rufinus - do you have a code snippet for me - my javascript skillset ist pretty basic so i dont really know how to work with your suggestion? :D

Comment: @Rufinus - May you help? :)

Comment: @AndyMay in your on click function after you call your addParticipationForm just call `$( ":checkbox" ).iCheck();` (or something similar - depending on your jquery plugin) - even better would be to limit the call to the content auf the inserted prototype. But most plugins  should be smart enough to not apply there markup if it already exists.

Comment: as statet in my solution, thats exactly what i did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not the very advanced Webdeveloper and the project i'm supporting was created by another person, i was not correct suspecting the checkboxes to be a bootstrap checkbox.

As a matter of fact it was a jquery checkbox wich i could initialize via .icheck()

Now it works. Thanks nevertheless to you both :)